# ODBC: Python gets data, C# doesn't..sometimes?

Tags: c#, python, sql-server, stored-procedures, odbc

This is a bit complex, but boils down to Python is successfully pulling the data and C# isn't.

Here is the SQL that is within a stored proc that sits on a remote server (Plexus).

**Statement1:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  CC.Serial_No,
  CC.Part_Operation_Key
INTO #Regrades
FROM Part_v_Container_Change2 AS CC

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Regrades
DROP TABLE #Regrades
RETURN;
```

This runs successfully by both C# and Python. When I add a join however C# no longer pulls any records but Python does. i.e.

**Statement2:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  CC.Serial_No,
  CC.Part_Operation_Key,
  PO.Operation_Key
INTO #Regrades
FROM Part_v_Container_Change2 AS CC
JOIN Part_v_Part_Operation AS PO
  ON PO.Part_Operation_Key = CC.Part_Operation_Key

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Regrades
DROP TABLE #Regrades
RETURN;
```

It gets a bit weirder though. Through playing with it I figured out it might have something to do with the temporary table. If I do a select and do not create this temporary table the data is successfully pulled by both programs (I need this temp table for later analysis though).

Because of this I thought I should use a create and insert shown below.

**Statement3:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
  Serial_No NVARCHAR(50),
  Part_Operation_Key INT,
  Operation_Key INT
);

INSERT #Test
(
  Serial_No,
  Part_Operation_Key,
  Operation_Key
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  CC.Serial_No,
  CC.Part_Operation_Key,
  PO.Operation_Key
FROM Part_v_Container_Change2 AS CC
JOIN Part_v_Part_Operation AS PO
  ON PO.Part_Operation_Key = CC.Part_Operation_Key
WHERE PO.Operation_Key = 32603 OR
      PO.Operation_Key = 33529;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Test
DROP TABLE #Test
RETURN;
```

Now here is the kicker. This fails in C# but works in Python. However, I had both statement 2, and 3 on the same stored proc while I was testing. If I commented out statement2, and then uncommented out statement3, statement3 ran in C# each and every time. This works in reverse too.

Here is the code for C#. I put it into a console app to make sure nothing else in the program was causing the problem.

**C#**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {      
            using (OdbcConnection connectionScalar = new OdbcConnection("DSN=XXXX; UID=XXXX; PWD=XXXX;"))
            {
                connectionScalar.Open();
                using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("sproc164407_2053096_650810", connectionScalar))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    var count = command.ExecuteScalar();
                    Console.WriteLine(count);
                    Console.WriteLine("Complete");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

**Python**

```
queryString = "{call sproc164407_2053096_650810 ()}"
connection = pyodbc.connect('DSN=xxxx; UID=xxxx; PWD=xxxx', autocommit = True)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(queryString)
recs=cursor.fetchall()
print(recs)
```

Python works everytime. If anyone can point me in the direction of what is going wrong, or what I can do to change this that would be great! I can run the python script but it's not very satisfactory to me to not know what the issue is.

Comment: Are your session settings different between the two? Things like ANSI_NULLS can affect how queries are processed. One heuristic to know this is whether there is more than one query plan in the plan cache for that procedure. A more brute force way would be to write a procedure that selects and returns those values from everything you can from the sessionproperty function.

Comment: Ben do you know how I would find this out I am not an expert by any means in databases.

Comment: Like I said above, try writing a procedure that does things like `select sessionproperty('ansi_nulls') as 'ansi_nulls', sessionproperty('ansi_padding') as 'ansi_padding', ...` and then call that from your application (or one with the same setup). If you're working with a DBA, they should be able to help you at least write the procedure.

Comment: Seems to be to do with the temp table I am creating. When I use CTE it works fine?

Comment: I've seen stranger things, but I will say that the use of a temp table in a stored procedure affecting results would be surprising to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as the first statement in the proc.  This will suppress `DONE_IN_PROC` messages (rowcounts) that can confuse some APIs.

I don't think you will have the problem in C# with the .NET Provider for SQL Server (SqlClient) and it will perform better than the ODBC from managed coe.

Comment: I actually do have that set to on. I should have shown that but it was right at the top of my sql.